# How do I create dynamic array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to create a dynamic array in typescript in the following format

```
const display = [
    { id: 1, displayName: "Abc1" },
    { id: 2, displayName: "Abc2" },
    { id: 3, displayName: "Abc3" }
]
```

I have tried the following codes

```
const [display, SetDisplay] = useState([])

function createData(id: number, name: string) {
    return { id, name };
}

SetDisplay(display.push(createData(1, "Abc1")))
```

But can not push data into the variable `display`. Getting error like

```
Argument of type '{ id: number; result: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Any information for resolving this would be helpful.

Comment: The second code is for inside of a react component -- is that what you are doing or do you just need simple help with an array in a non-react program?

Comment: Also keep in mind that return value of the push method is **not the mutated source** but only resulting **length** of the mutated source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not mutate the state directly.

You can directly do a setState and destructure your previous array to add new data.

You can as well type your setState as follow `<{id: number; name:string}>`

```js
const [display,setDisplay] = useState<{id: number; name:string}>([]);

function createData(id: number, name: string) {
  setDisplay((prev) => [...prev, { id, name } ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the type to the ‍‍`useState`:

```
const [display,SetDisplay] = 
  useState<{id: number,name: string}[]>([]);
```